# How to use foreignObject in svg.js 3.0?

Tags: svg.js

My older code for version 2.6.5 works.

```
<div id="drawing"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.js"></script>
<script src="/nbextensions/google.colab/svg.foreignobject.js"></script>
<script>
var draw = SVG('drawing').size('100%', 100)

var fobj = draw.foreignObject(100,100).attr({id: 'fobj'})
fobj.appendChild("span", {
  id: 'myspan', innerText: "Hello"
})
```

My new code for version 3.0.12 doesn't.

```
<div id='drawing'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.12/svg.js"></script>
<script>
var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size('100%', 100)

var fobj = draw.foreignObject(100,100)
fobj.appendChild("span", {
  id: 'myspan', innerText: "Hello"
})
```

The [release note] says 3.0.12 supports foreignObject. How do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the already correct answer, you can also use `SVG('<span>').attr(...)` to create your html which you want to add.

```
const fObj = canvas.foreignObject(100, 100)
fObj.add(SVG('<span>').attr(...))
```

You can even add html directly:

```
fObj.add('<span id="bla">Hello</span>')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just try to use foreignObject as a Container, by using add. And create a SPAN element first. Now it works.

```
var fobj = draw.foreignObject(100,100)
var span = document.createElement('span')
span.innerText = 'Hello'
fobj.add(span)
```